# How do I derive the coordinates of the shortest possible paths in a 2D array (similar to leetcode shortest bridge but with coordinates)

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am trying to find the shortest path between two islands(represented by 1) in a 2D array. I want to get the coordinates(row, col) to form possible bridges but with shortest path.

So far I have used DFS to identify the islands and their coordinates that formed them.
I am trying to get the function to return the coordinates of possible bridges to be built.

For e.g bridges can be built at coordinate (1,2) or (2,1)

Example:

```
grid = [
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
]
```

You can see that there are 2 islands found separated by water (zeros)

My current code only returns the island found and the coordinates that make the islands as a dictionary e.g 2 Islands

```
{`**`1`**`: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)], `**`2`**`: [(2, 2), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]}
```

```html
grid = [
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
]

def find_bridge(grid):
    vacant_land_indices = []

    town_dict = {}

    counter = 0

    # TODO: edit this function.
    # Run DFS to identify island
    # Add identified island into queue
    # Run BFS

    # dimension
    no_of_row, no_of_col = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    direction = [[0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [-1, 0]]

    def invalid_coordinate(r, c):
        return r < 0 or c < 0 or r >= no_of_row or c >= no_of_col or grid[r][c] != 1  # boolean value

    def dfs(r, c):
        visit = set()

        if invalid_coordinate(r, c) or (r, c) in visit:  # check not: within grid, one, visit
            return

        visit.add((r, c))  # part of first island we are visiting

        grid[r][c] = 0

        if counter not in town_dict:
            town_dict[counter] = [(r, c)]

        else:
            town_dict[counter].append((r, c))

        # directions
        for dr, dc in direction:
            dfs(r + dr, c + dc)

    for r in range(no_of_row):
        for c in range(no_of_col):
            if grid[r][c] == 1:  # piece of land

                counter += 1

                dfs(r, c)  # fills visit hash set with one of the islands

    print(town_dict)
    for key in town_dict:
        print(key)


find_bridge(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudocode:

1. You want to use a dictionary to store all coordinates of the towns in each town council. Use DFS to traverse the grid and record the coordinates of each town.
2. Then, loop through the dictionary to find the coordinates of the 2 closest towns between 2 town councils. Record this information in a new array.
3. From that array, determine the vertical and horizontal steps (coordinates) to take to reach one town to the other. Add the coordinates to the output list

Here's the sample code:

```
def find_vacant_lands(map):
    count = 1
    townDict = {}
    townCoordinates = []
  
    if len(map)==0:
        return []

    rows, cols = len(map), len(map[0])

    # Using DFS to find each town coordinates and storing them in a dictionary
    # where the key is the town council and the values are the coordinates of 
    # each town in the town council 
    def DFS(x, y, r, c, map):
        if not (x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= r or y >= c or map[x][y]!=1):
        #Mark town as visited
            map[x][y] = 'v'
            tup = (x,y)
            townCoordinates.append(tup)

            #Traverse clockwise through top, right, down, left direction
            DFS(x-1, y, r, c, map) #Top
            DFS(x, y+1, r, c, map) #Right
            DFS(x+1, y, r, c, map) #Down
            DFS(x, y-1, r, c, map) #Left 

    #Iterating through the map and applying DFS
    for x in range(rows):
        for y in range(cols):
            if map[x][y] == 1:
                DFS(x, y, rows, cols, map)
                townDict[count] = townCoordinates
                townCoordinates = []
                count += 1

    nearestTowns = []

    # Function to find the towns from each town council nearest to each other 
    def nearestPoints(a, b):
        li = []
        m = 999999999999

        # Finding distance between each towns from each respective town councils
        # Also determining the smallest distance i.e. Manhattan distance between 2 towns 
        for cor in a:
            for corr in b:
                dist = abs(cor[0] - corr[0]) + abs(cor[1] - corr[1])
                if dist < m:
                    m = dist
                points = (cor, corr, dist)
                li.append(points)
        
        # Looping through li and finding the points with the smallest distance 
        for points in li:
            if points[-1] == m:
                return (points[0], points[1])

    # Iterate through all towns in each TC and determine the nearest towns 
    for tc, coordinates in townDict.items():
        if tc != len(townDict):
            res = nearestPoints(coordinates, townDict[tc+1])
            nearestTowns.append(res)
        else:
            break
        
    vacant_land_indices = [] 

    # Determine the coordinates to connect the nearest towns together 
    for towns in nearestTowns:

        x1, y1 = towns[0][0], towns[0][1] 
        x2, y2 = towns[1][0], towns[1][1] 

        # When one TC is above the another  
        if x1 < x2:

            if y2 < y1:
                m = y2
                o = x1
                for n in range(x1,x2):
                    vPath = (n,m) # Coordinates of vertical climb path
                    # Ensure no repeated coordinates will be added in the final result 
                    if vPath not in vacant_land_indices: 
                        vacant_land_indices.append(vPath)
                for p in range(y2+1, y1):
                    hPath = (o,p) # Coordinates of horizontal path
                    if hPath not in vacant_land_indices:
                        vacant_land_indices.append(hPath)

            elif y1 < y2:
                m = y2
                o = x1
                for n in range(x1,x2):
                    vPath = (n,m)
                    if vPath not in vacant_land_indices:
                        vacant_land_indices.append(vPath)
                for p in range(y1+1, y2):
                    hPath = (o,p)
                    if hPath not in vacant_land_indices:
                        vacant_land_indices.append(hPath)

            # When one TC is located right below another TC
            elif y1 == y2:
                m = y1
                for n in range(x1+1,x2):
                    vPath = (n,m)
                    if vPath not in vacant_land_indices:
                        vacant_land_indices.append(vPath)

        # If TCs are located on the same plane 
        elif x1 == x2:
            o = x1
            for p in range(y1+1, y2):
                hPath = (o,p)
                if hPath not in vacant_land_indices:
                    vacant_land_indices.append(hPath)

    # Return sorted results 
    return sorted(vacant_land_indices, key=lambda tup: (tup[0],tup[1]))
```